# Form validation not running

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to run a form validation on an HTML form to make sure the person has filled out the two password  fields same . And its not working,I am using Netbeans 8.0.2. Thanks in advance for helping me track down the problem.

My Html form and JavaScript validation code is:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> home </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function matchpass() {

        var fpass = document.myform.pass.value;
        var spass = document.myform.pass1.value;
        if (fpass === spass) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Password must be same");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myform" action="register.jsp" onsubmit="return matchpass();">
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="pass" />
        <br> Re-enter Password:
        <input type="password" name="pass1" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yejbv526/ Working for me

Comment: You should tell us what is not working. An error ? Doing nothing ?

Comment: works fine with me too. what does netbeans have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

try this , it seems to me that you do not catch values

`<form name="myform" action="register.jsp" onsubmit="return matchpass(this);">`

```
function matchpass(value) {
```